# MySQL: Joining different tables based on an if/case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, case

I have a table with two sets of IDs (dec_id and rec_id). If dec_id is found in Table1, I need to left join that table. If not - left join table2. The same goes for the second column. I also need to know which ID was found in which table.

Here's the abstract structure of Table 1:

```
dec_id     rec_id     
-----------------
11         16
23         24
15         31
```

Tables 2 and 3 are for all intends and purposes identical (apart from the actual data):

```
id        name         data1         data2
------------------------------------------
11        a            x             p
41        b            y             q
55        c            z             r
```

And the logic (abstract):

```
IF (dec_id IS IN Table1) {
    LEFT JOIN Table1 on (dec_id = table1.id);
    LEFT JOIN Table2 on (rec_id = table2.id);
    FLAG = 1;
} ELSE {
    LEFT JOIN Table1 on (rec_id = table1.id);
    LEFT JOIN Table2 on (dec_id = table2.id);
    FLAG = 0;
}
LEFT JOIN Table3, Table4, ...
```

I know the result can be achieved in PHP with more than one query, but I'd like to avoid it if possible for the sake of efficiency; unfortunately my SQL knowledge fails me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.id, t3.id) id,
       (t2.id IS NOT NULL) flag,
       COALESCE(t2.name, t3.name) name,
       COALESCE(t2.data1, t3.data1) data1
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.dec_id = t2.id LEFT JOIN table3 t3
    ON t1.rec_id = t3.id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9ac1/2)** demo